# Get range of Eloc according to radius? Can we use Eloc as geohash? Can someone share an example?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, mapmyindia-api

I want to use eloc as geoahsh .. to store points in my database, and query according to the distance. I am using flutter sdk, for android and ios

I have done this using geohash, is it possible to do with eloc?a any support is appreciated.